# Angular 5 router-outlet, JWT

Tags: angular, rest, api, jwt

I need to add the token attributes to my components like this:

```
<div>
  <app-authentication [(token)]='token'></app-authentication>
</div>
```

But the routing handles my components so I have no idea how I could implemnent the

```
[(token)]='token'
```

part.

Currently my app.component.html looks like this:

```
<app-header></app-header>
<div class="container">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

And app-routing.module.ts like this:

```
import { NgModule, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ProjectListComponent } from './projects/project-list/project-list.component';
import { ProjectsViewComponent } from './projects/projects-view/projects-view.component';
import { AdminComponent } from './admin/admin.component';
import { Headers } from '@angular/http';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ProjectListComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'admin',
    component: AdminComponent
  },
  {
    path: ':slug',
    component: ProjectsViewComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: []
})
export class Wpng2RoutingModule {}
```

Comment: from what purpose you are going to use an @Input for token? if this method is to validate access to a component you can use guard in the router to restrict access to protected component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use dependency injection to provide the token. You can set it up like this.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';

export const JWT = new InjectionToken<string>('JWT');

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers: [
    AuthService,
    {
      provide: JWT,
      useFactory: (auth: AuthService) => authService.jwt,
      deps: [AuthService],
    },
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**any.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';

@Component({ selector: 'any' })
export class AnyComponent {
   constructor(@Inject(JWT) public jwt: string) {
      // do something with the token
   }
}
```